# Spotfire textArea export to PDF

Tags: ironpython, spotfire, spotfire-analyst

Right now I can only export the textArea you can see on the screen. (The first page of information)

The scrollable information below does not export.

I've seen as recently as last year this problem has not been solved.

Has there been any update information here to make it possible to export an entire textArea to PDF.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
pdfexpsettings.IncludeNonVisibleContent=True

pdfexpsettings.Scope = ExportScope.ActivePage
```

Comment: If you work through the GUI to set up a prepared report that is formatted correctly to allow all content to fit on the screen, you can just call to export that specific report in python, and not leave it up to Spotfire to build the report without you.

Comment: Spotfire wont allow for a textArea to export more than the viewable screen. Any other visualizations you can prepare the report to export everything to pdf but Spotfire doesn't consider textArea as a visualization.
I'm wondering if there is a ironpython solution to potentially change the textArea setting in the backend to allow the whole textArea exported to a pdf.